# Jquery deleting hover class

Tags: jquery, menubar, jquery-hover

I have created one html table to behave like a menu. It works great on page load. However, after selecting some menu item, the hover class is not working for any menu item.

JQuery:

```
$('.menuItem').click(function () {
    $('.menuItem').css({ "background-color": "#e56d15", "border-radius": "6px", "border": "1px solid #e56d15", "color" : "white"});

    $(this).css({ "background-color": "#f0cc5e", "color": "#552604", "border": "1px solid white" });
        // Display correct section of page
        switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
            case "miHome":
                $('.subPages').each(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
                $('#pgHome').show(1000);
                break;
            case "miAbout":
                $('.subPages').each(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
                $('#pgAbout').show(1000);
                break;
            case "miMembers":
                $('.subPages').each(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
                $('#pgMembers').show(1000);
                break;
            case "miEvents":
                $('.subPages').each(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
                $('#pgEvents').show(1000);
                break;
            case "miFGal":
                $('.subPages').each(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
                $('#pgFGal').show(1000);
                break;
            case "miVGal":
                $('.subPages').each(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
                $('#pgVGal').show(1000);
                break;
            default:
                //$('.subPages').hide();
                //$('#pgHome').show();
                break;
        }
    });
```

Here is HTML:

```
            <table class="horCellSpacing">
                <tr>
                    <td class="menuItem" id="miHome">Home</td><td class="menuItem" id="miAbout">About Us</td><td class="menuItem" id="miMembers">Members</td>
                    <td class="menuItem" id="miEvents">Events</td><td class="menuItem" id="miFGal">Photo Gallery</td><td class="menuItem" id="miVGal">Video Gallery</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

and Here is CSS:

```
.menuItem {
    font-size: small; text-align: center; min-width: 100px; padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; transition-duration: 0.5s;
    background-color: #e56d15; border-radius: 6px; border: 1px solid #e56d15; transition-property: all;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #ffc194, inset 0px 0px 10px 3px #ffab6d;
}
.menuItem:hover {
    cursor: pointer; background-color: #f0cc5e; border: 1px solid white; color: #552604; font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: That's because you are setting the css to the button. Try setting another class instead and style it in the css.

Answer (score 0):

Try using toggleClass:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2Mh3/)

**JQuery:**

```
$('.menuItem').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
    cursor: pointer; background-color: #f0cc5e; 
    border: 1px solid white; 
    color: #552604; 
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, it is not working as expected.
I am not able to understand why, menuItem:hover class is getting unregistered. And how to link it back to menuItems

Comment: Can we not do something like:
`$('.menuItem:hover').css({ "background-color": "#f0cc5e", "border-radius": "6px", "border": "1px solid #e56d15", "color" : "#552604"});`

Comment: If you observe, your JSFiddle is allowing you to show multiple items active at the same time. Can we fix that?